# Why do i keep getting none when doing web scraping in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

This is the code that I wrote. I watched lot of tutorials but they get the output with exactly the same code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url="https://shop.punamflutes.com/pages/5150194068881408"
page=requests.get(url).text
soup=bs(page,'lxml')
#print(soup)
tag=soup.find('div',class_="flex xs12")
print(tag)
```

I always get none. Also the class name seems strange. The view source code has different stuff than the inspect element thing

Answer (score 0):

Bs4 is weird. Sometimes it returns different code than what is on the page...it alters it depending on the source. Try using selenium. It works great and has many more uses than bs4. Most of all...it is super easy to find elements on a site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bs4 problem, it is correctly parsing what `requests` returns. It rather depends on the webpage itself

If you inspect the "soup", you will see that the source of the page is a set of links to scripts that render the content on the page. In order for these scripts to be executed, you need to have a browser - requests will only get you what the webserver returns, but won't execute the javascript for you. You can verify this yourself by deactivating javascript in the developer tools of your browser.

The solution is to use a web browser (e.g. headless chrome + chromedriver) and Selenium to control it. There are plenty of good tutorials out there on how to do this.